# Regular expression to allow only negative number

Tags: regex

This sounds like it would be a fairly common issue, but I've searched a lot and can't find anything that works.  I'm using the jquery validate plug-in to validate form input.  There's a field which needs to accept only negative numbers (can be whole integers or decimals but must be less than zero).

I've tried doing something like this:

```
    $.validator.addClassRules("negativeNumber", { range: [-1000000000, 0] });
```

...which works okay, but the validation error is horrible ("Please enter a number between -1000000000 and 0") - I'd like it to just say "Please enter a negative number".

Could anyone point me in the direction of a regex that only allows negative numbers?

Many thanks folks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a regex, you can add a [custom validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod), which I believe is easier to read.

```
$.validator.addMethod('negativeNumber',
    function (value) { 
        return Number(value) < 0;
    }, 'Enter a negative number');
```

Answer (score 4):

I would think `\-\d*(\.?\d+)` would do it.

`\-` matches a minus

`\d*` matches zero or more digits (to account for things like -.5)

`\.?` matches a decimal point if it's there

`\d*` matches zero or more digits

Comment: Yup!  Awesome, thanks.  Will mark as answer as soon as I'm able to :)

Comment: Thanks! Though I do feel obligated to say that the *typical* way to do this would be a validation method. So if you feel like accepting one of the other answers, it won't hurt my feelings. If you use mine though, I'll appreciate the accept :)

Comment: @CaffGeek I was assuming a standard for format, but I guess you're right, when we're taking user input. Editing

Comment: I posted the regex below, it's `\-\d*(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @CaffGeek Oh, I hope you don't mind me using your suggestion.. Is that ok?

Comment: Nah, you could also just switch the + and * around in yours

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt, you need to change the last part of yours to `\d+` instead of `\d*`, or you match juts a `-` by itself (and thanks)

Comment: @CaffGeek Whoops. I actually did that on purpose so I would match things like `1.`, which are used in certain contexts. I also didn't want my answer to be the exact same as yours, lol. But I didn't think about it matching just a hyphen.

Comment: This regex will allow   '-4-4' this as well which is not a valid number

Comment: @SupreetSingh no it won't.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt It will, I have tested this on https://regexr.com/ . You can test it over there and let me know if I'm doing a mistake. I tested with your expression \-\d*(\.?\d+)

Comment: @SupreetSingh it doesn't match the entire expression "-4-4", it matches "-4" twice because regexr (by default) adds the global (/g) flag to the pattern. You can turn it off by clicking "flags" at the top right and deselecting "global". After you do, it will only match the first "-4".

Answer (score 1):

This will match anything less than 0 `\-\d*(\.\d+)?`

Including -.00001, -100000, and -1

Answer (score 0):

This would be so much easier with a custom validation method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('negativeNumber', function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (+value < 0);
}, 'Please enter a negative number');
```

That is much nicer (and probably quicker) than regex, and let's the browser parse the number for you, rather than doing it yourself with regex.

---

Or, of course, use the `max` method, although the message there isn't quite as nice.